# Is it possible to clear the cache of map tiles on the Google Maps for iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, google-maps, caching, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the latest version of the Google Maps for iOS SDK.  I noticed that the SDK stores a cache of map tiles in the GMSCacheStorage directory in my apps filesystem.  I have not found a way through the SDK to clear this cache.  Is there any known workaround for emptying the Tiles.sqlite file that holds the cached data?

I was able to just delete the file off the file system to clear the data, but it does not regenerate, so no future caching would be done.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no there is no public api for that.

---

you can fake a memory warning notification and gms will clear... a bit
(note this isnt App Store safe)

I also class-dumped the sdk and found methods with promising names but they don't really seem to help more than the notification (which also doesn't help much)

Comment: Thanks for the input, that's what I thought.  Seems weird that we can't control clearing the cache, I have users that are reporting pretty substantial size increases because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found solution which deallocates significant memory usage accumulated just by dragging and pinching on the map (which happens even offline) I use .terrain mapType and memory accumulates from 300mb to 500mb pretty quickly during use.)

```
 mapView.mapType = .none
 mapView.mapType = .terrain
```

Memory usage drops back to 300mb and I use this reset in timer.